# recursively, how many numbers of maximum n digits (base-5) without the sequence 21

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, recursion

If   $T_n$ is the amount of numbers with maximum $n$ digits (in base 5), that do not have a 21 sequence find a recurrence relation for $T_n$.

My solution is $T_n = 5T_{n-1} - T_{n-2}$;$T_0 = 1 , T_1 = 5$

I also tested this for n=2 and n=3, but I'm still not sure if this is correct (since I find contradicting results for n=4)

Can someone confirm if this is correct?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you get to your recursion?

Comment: I think your solution should be correct, you first take all the elements of $T_{n-1}$ and add any digit to each of them, giving us $5T_{n-1}$, now we substract all the elements starting with string "21", but there is exactly $T_{n-2}$ of those as each element we substract is formed by adding the string "21" onto the original shorter element. I don't know how you got the mistake when calculating by hand.

Comment: thanks! this is exactly how I got my answer. I believe I made a mistake when calculating by hand for n=4 , but I was suspicious towards my solution from the very beginning (which is why I started calculating by hand)

Comment: How should we treat leading zeros? It seems you assumed that a sequence of $n$ zeros makes a valid $n$-digit number, but is this assumption ok?